# Is Django-Tagging still maintained?

Tags: django, django-tagging

Last contribution to github has been on 2010_01_22, which is more than 2 years now. Tagging still works, but will it continue to? Is it just so well written it doesn't need maintaining for such a long time? Or do i just have the wrong source with https://github.com/brosner/django-tagging?

Comment: Could one of the downvoters please explain why they downvoted? This is a question which can be answered without asking for opinions. And i can't find information on Google if the app is still maintained, as i wanted to know.

Comment: Ah, looks like it isn't a legitimate question to ask if an open source project has been abandoned two years after the last update. Interesting :D

Comment: [Marco Fucci](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231226/marco-fucci) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/204002) "Just to be clear, using django-tagging 0.3.1 might not be recommended at the moment as the current version has problems and limitations. You should use another django app instead."

Comment: [Issue 279 - Doesn't work on Django 1.5](https://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/detail?id=279&start=100) seems to indicate that the module requires updating.  Longstanding issues go unanswered.  [Issue 273](https://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/detail?id=273&start=100) is interesting as well.  Check the [issue queue](https://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/list) and come to your own conclusions whether you should rely on django-tagging for your projects.  I've used it in the past, it's a good module, but unsupported for a long time.

Comment: Just noticed https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-tagging-ng which appears to be taking django-tagging forward and has some commits in September 2014 (though no commits in the previous two years).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just a clone of http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/ which works perfectly and is a very well written app. There is also a good alternative called django-taggit https://github.com/alex/django-taggit

Comment: Code on code.google.com is not newer than the one on github. Question persists.

Comment: not really. just because the code hasn't been updated doesn't mean there is anything wrong with it. All the tagging apps do exactly what you need and have nothing wrong with them.

Comment: Ok, so i assume django-tagging is still state of the art. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: django-tagging is not compatible with django1.5+

Comment: Colin Anderson: Where did you get that info about the incompatibility?

Comment: [django-tagging](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-tagging) is now maintained by [Julien Fache](https://github.com/Fantomas42). This is confirmed by the author/maintainer information on [Python's package index PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tagging#downloads). Julien has taken over the project in [February 2014](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues/320#issuecomment-34449086). Since then it has been in continuous development. I would say, Julien's name alone is proof enough that the project is finally active again, and in a well-maintained state.